# Java IO Exception - Selenium GRID

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am new to Grid. I am able to start the Hub and a couple of RC servers, but when I am trying to run my test case, I am getting typical JAVA IO error. Below is error stack on one of the RC servers.

```
<error>
[java] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run
program "/usr/lib/firefox-3.0.19/firefox": java.io.IOException:
error=12, Cannot allocate memory
<error>
```

How do I handle this in Selenium grid? I remember using `-Xmx` and `-Xm`s to set max memory usage in the application servers. Is there any similar way to setting memory space for grid?

Comment: Are you able to open firefox manually? And are you starting your Hub and RC in same machine?

Comment: Are you starting grid nodes via rake or ant?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it's a Java issue.  It looks like your machine is just out of memory.  Take a look at the output of "free" to verify.